# The entire User Interface freezes/becomes unresponsive for up to 20 seconds

Tags: freeze

I am a rails developer, using Ubuntu 13.10 installed on a Asus S550C Ultrabook (was a windows 8 machine originally)

Every day I work with Sublime Text 2, Google Chrome, and Terminal (about 6 tabs open)

The problem:

clicking on the menu bar (eg File -> Save) while using Sublime Text 2 will occasionally (eg almost always) make the ENTIRE COMPUTER freeze for up to 20 seconds.

This occasionally happens when I go to log out / lock my computer. Sometimes it doesn't freeze completely but rather is just very sluggish and then recovers.

I don't know if this is a problem with Sublime Text 2, or the Ubuntu 13.10 operating system.

(Thanks for reading)
Best Regards

Comment: It is said that Sublime having this issue with certain people. May be because it has high analysis and detecting function. See [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1p1yay/lime_an_opensource_sublimetext_editor_compatible/).

Comment: Today I installed Gnome as my desktop (instead of Unity) and the problem seems to be fixed. Sublime menus no longer freeze.

Comment: Post your finding as an answer.

Comment: I run it with sudo, and my problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be fixed ---> I installed Gnome as my desktop (instead of Unity) and Sublime menus no longer freeze.

I typed this in terminal:

sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback

...then:

After the installation is complete, log out of your current Ubuntu session. From here, click Ubuntu icon in the top right corner of the login screen. You’ll be presented with options for all currently installed desktop environments. The latest addition to this list will be Gnome Classic. Click this option, and select OK to be prompted for your login credentials. When you have logged in, the Unity interface will be gone and you’ll be back to the way Ubuntu used to be (Gnome).

Found the solution at:
http://www.geek.com/chips/dont-uninstall-ubuntu-just-change-the-interface-1542514/